# How do I access $_POST variables from a jquery .post?

Tags: php, jquery, post, http-post

I am trying to using jquery post to try to send form data asynchronously to a php file that will upload the data to my database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contact_form">  
    <form id="contact" name="contact" method="post">  
  <fieldset>  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  

    <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  

    <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>  
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  

    <br />  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />  
  </fieldset>  
</form>  
</div>  
  <div id="result"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#submit_btn").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

 $.post("process.php", $("#contact").serialize());


  return false;
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know it is serial encoding the data but my php script isn't picking it up, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I know it is simple, but I have been working a few days on this and can't seem to figure it out. I understand how to do this without jquery but I really need it in this case. Here is my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $var_name = $_POST['name'];
    $var_email = $_POST['email'];
    $var_phone = $_POST['phone'];

//This establishes a connection to the database. It also says what to do if the connection fails.
try {
    $db_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $db_username, $db_password);
    $db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $db_handle->prepare('INSERT INTO contact(name, email, phone) VALUES(:name, :email, :phone)');   
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':name' => $var_name,
        ':email' => $var_email,
        ':phone' => $var_phone,
        ));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you serialize a form with jQuery, submit button is not included so you should replace

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

by

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```

**EDIT**

Change `$("#submit_btn").submit(...);` by `$("#contact").submit(...);`

Comment: I did this but it's not working, I am trying to figure out how to see the var_dump of the page, to see if it is getting anything.

Comment: I saw your problem, check my edit. You are suppose to submit the form not the button :).

Comment: A million times YES!!! I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't figure out what! Man I have bashed my head for days on this. I feel stupid and relieved at the same time, thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("contact").serialize()
```

Should be:

```
$("#contact").serialize()
```

Your selector is incorrect, so you aren't actually sending anything to the server. Next time, check the request in your browser tools.

Comment: Hey speaking of which, I tried that first and it wasn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

The jquery API states that submit button values will not be passed. So the post may be getting to your php request just fine would suggest looking for a required field instead of looking for $_POST['submit'] in your conditional.

You can also try using var_dump($_POST) before your code and see what is getting to the script.

Comment: I tried changing the $_POST['submit'] to $_POST['name'] but I still couldn't get it to work. I'm working on trying to return a var_dump of the post array now.